# SQLServer reference outer query

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to reference an outer query from an inner query in the context of a join? The "where (sid.ItemID = i.itemID)" of the inner query is giving me an error. I thought I did this in the past so I search through all my stored procs but apparently I did some kind of substitution to get it to work. I suspect I can delete that line and it will work but is it more effecient with that inner where clause?

```
SELECT departmentName
       , supplierName
       , so.SalesOrderID
       , ss.warehouseInvoiceNo
       , ss.transactionNo
       , ss.storeID
       , s.storeName
       , s.storeNo
       , tr.transactionDate
       , p.period
       , sooos.salesOrderID
       , sooos.salesOrderOutOfStockID
       , sooos.itemID
       , i.itemNo
       , i.itemName
       , i.pack
       , i.unitSize
       , quantity
       , wi.available
FROM   SalesOrderOutOfStock sooos
       JOIN Item AS i ON i.ItemID = sooos.ItemID
       JOIN SalesOrder so ON so.SalesOrderID = sooos.SalesOrderID
       JOIN WarehouseInventory wi ON wi.ItemID = sooos.ItemID
       JOIN Store s ON s.StoreID = so.StoreID
       JOIN InvoiceOrderRelationship ior ON ior.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
       JOIN StockSale ss ON ss.WarehouseInvoiceNo = ior.WarehouseInvoiceNo
       JOIN TransactionRegister tr ON tr.TransactionNo = ss.TransactionNo
       JOIN Period p ON p.PeriodID = tr.PeriodID
       JOIN Department d ON d.DepartmentID = i.DepartmentID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 itemID
                                     , supplierID
                        FROM   SupplierInvoiceDetail sid
                               JOIN SupplierInvoice si ON si.SupplierInvoiceID = sid.SupplierInvoiceID
                       --where (sid.ItemID = i.itemID) 
                       order by InvoiceDate desc 
                       --NEED AN ORDER BY HERE
                       ) AS lastSupplier ON lastSupplier.ItemID = i.ItemID
       JOIN supplier su ON su.SupplierID = Isnull(lastSupplier.supplierID, i.supplierID)
WHERE  ss.WarehouseInvoiceNo = 10000000
```

--$P{invoiceNo}

Comment: hmmm ... not sure why it is formatted like that

Comment: Use [`OUTER APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of `LEFT JOIN`, this will give you access to the outer fields.

Comment: Formatting: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (Or, you can just highlight the code block and hit the `{}` button)

Comment: Please notice you have a subquery using top 1 with no order by. When you don't have an order by you have no way of knowing which row you will get back.

Comment: Thank you Damien. Sean I will edit and insert line

Comment: Gareth, that "outer Apply" did it. Thank you sir! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`OUTER APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) here rather than `LEFT JOIN`:

```
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 itemID
                                 , supplierID
                    FROM   SupplierInvoiceDetail sid
                           JOIN SupplierInvoice si ON si.SupplierInvoiceID = sid.SupplierInvoiceID
                   where (sid.ItemID = i.itemID) order by InvoiceDate desc 
                   ) AS lastSupplier
```

Subqueries introduced in `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses cannot refer to *other* table sources within the same `FROM` clause (effectively, they should all be evaluatable simultaneously). `APPLY` allows you to introduce a specific dependency in the evaluation.